# Decoding krypto parameter in Websphere Commerce

Tags: encryption, websphere-commerce, wcs

I am trying to decode the "krypto" parameter used by Websphere Commerce (to integrate a new system with a legacy WCS 6.x). Unfortunately I can't find a lot of information about the krypto parameter. According to a [Security Advisory](http://www.vsecurity.com/download/advisories/20130619-1.txt) the krypto parameter should be first base64 encoded and then encoded with DES3-CBC. I do have the Merchant Key used to encode it, I think - can't verify I got the right one though.

I tried to

1. Take the WCS-generated krypto parameter from the URL
2. URL-decode it (decodeURIComponent)
3. Call openssl like this for the base64 and Triple DES decoding:

> openssl des3 -d -base64 -in krypto.txt -out krypto-out.txt

Currently I am getting a "bad magic number" error from openssl. I wonder whether anyone successfully reverse-engineered the parameter and has more details about the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Merchant Key value you are using the decrypted value of the key? (Where have you got the Merchant Key from?)
The Websphere Commerce configuration file contains the encrypted key value. However, you need to use the decrypted key value to decrypt other encrypted values.

The parts you state above appear correct, although I can't verify the decryption method using the openssl tool. I typically use WCS's nc_crypt utility for these decryptions.

Comment: It should be unencrypted (not from a config file), but I can't really check.